# PowerShell Entering-PSSession Failed

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, powershell, remote-control

I'm trying to learn more about PowerShell and scripting! and I'm stuck at remoting.

I have 2 VMs running on my PC:

1. Server DC (all configured properly)
2. Windows 10 server

Ping results are replaying with 0% loss on both ends, the Windows VM joined the domain, so all looks right but still getting an error, even though I enabled remoting on both VMs:

- enable-psremoting
- set-WSmanquickconfig
- added both ends to the trusted devices list

All came back with no errors.

The issue here is when I'm trying to Enter-PSSsession as attached below and the EM is also added:

[image]

Pic1 is the windows server and my domain controller(DC1)
Pic2 is my windows VM.

Any idea what's wrong here?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Have you tried using a `-Credential $cred` argument, where `$cred = Get-Credential`?  Also, have you tried the IP address or fully-qualified hostname, instead of the short hostname?

Comment: @leeharvey1 I have tried both and still got the same errors

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for the note, will do that

Comment: On your windows 10 VM, are you logged in **as** a domain user that has administrator rights on the DC? Make sure you read through the troubleshooting guide as well, since it covers a lot of the weird cases: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7.2